# how do I separate each tr in a table in python?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse table from http://www.livescore.co.uk/worldcup/tables/.I am having trouble in managing the output.I want to show only text in the output and also i want to put a break each tr after all the td is shown.I am Beginner and i am trying to learn.So can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong.Any suggestions?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

pageSource=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/worldcup/tables/').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"class":"league-wc table bh"} )
results=[]
for table in alltables:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    lines=[]
    for tr in rows[1:]:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:

            text=td.renderContents().strip('\n')

            lines.append(text)




    text_table='\n'.join(lines) 
    print text_table
```

output:

```
<a href="/worldcup/team-brazil/">Brazil</a> 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
 <a href="/worldcup/team-cameroon/">Cameroon</a> 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
 <a href="/worldcup/team-croatia/">Croatia</a> 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
 <a href="/worldcup/team-mexico/">Mexico</a> 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
 ....similar
```

My Desire output:

```
1,brazil,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,cameroon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,craotia,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4,Meico,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

pageSource=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/worldcup/tables/').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"class":"league-wc table bh"} )

results=[]
for table in alltables:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    _table = []
    for tr in rows[1:]:
        _row = []
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            if td.findAll('a'):
                text=td.a.renderContents().strip()
            else:
                text=td.renderContents().strip()
            _row.append(text)
        _table.append(_row)
    results.append(_table)


# print results
index = 1
for table in results:
    for row in table:
        print ','.join([str(index)] + row[1:])
        index += 1
```

Output:

```
1,Brazil,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,Cameroon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,Croatia,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4,Mexico,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
5,Australia,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6,Chile,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
...
```

The idea is collect raw data first, and then write logics to show the data (in whatever ways).